# How to add Multiple columns to the existing Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have to add multiple column to the existing dataframe without any static value. I tried with **[withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)** `dataframe.withColumn(c,col(c))` but I have more than 10 columns to add. How can I do that ?

Comment: what will be the values for those columns ?

Comment: Seq(col1,col2,col3 ... col10).foldLeft(ds)((acc,c) => acc.withColumn(c,col(c)))???

Comment: Yes @AndrzejJozwik I am looking something like that.

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val newDs:DataFrame =Seq("col1","col2","col3").foldLeft[DataFrame](ds)(
     (acc,c) => 
          acc.withColumn(c,col(c))
     )
```